# Problem with Dynamic Sendgrid and -webkit

Tags: html, css, email, webkit, sendgrid

I had a problem with dynamic templates and the style options of css: "-webkit-line-clamp: 4;" and "-webkit-box-orient: vertical;", when i send the e-mails, the dynamic template removes these styles.

[image: Code]

[image: Browser]

Comment: Please copy and paste your code instead of sharing screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SendGrid doesn't strip CSS out of your emails for you, but email clients will. Most email clients only support and render a subset of CSS. You can check out the support of email clients for CSS with sites like [Can I email...](https://www.caniemail.com/) or [Campaign Monitor's ultimate guide to email CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

However, I couldn't find mention of either `-webkit-line-clamp` or `-webkit-box-orient` in either of those references. As far as I understand, email clients have an allow-list of CSS properties, so if those two aren't mentioned by the online references and appear stripped from your email, then neither are currently supported by the email clients you are testing in.

The only advice here is to limit your CSS to relatively simple CSS or check with *Can I Email...*  to see if the CSS you want to use is supported.